# Javascript Click Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a MVC view with various functions that are working correctly, I am trying to add a function to highlight list rows and have added the following to my scripts section

```
        $(function () {
        $('.list-group').click(function (e) {
            alert('1');
            e.preventDefault()
            alert('2');
            $that = $(this);

            $('.list-group').find('li').removeClass('active-searchitem');
            $that.addClass('active-searchitem');
        });
    })
```

This is not the finished function but I am not even hitting the first alert. The following is in my view

```
<div id="searchResults">
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px">
    <div class="panel-heading">Search Results</div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 700px; overflow-y: scroll">
        <ul class="list-group">
            @if (Model.fuzzyFind != null)
            {
                var classIcon = "";
                foreach (WebReg2.Models.FuzzyFind find in Model.fuzzyFind)
                {
                    if (find.SmallIcon == "Elector") { classIcon = "fa fa-user fa-1x"; }
                    if (find.SmallIcon == "ElectorPostal") { classIcon = "fa fa-user fa-1x"; }
                    if (find.SmallIcon == "Deleted") { classIcon = "fa fa-trash fa-1x"; }
                    if (find.SmallIcon == "Property Void") { classIcon = "fa fa-home fa-1x"; }

                    <li class="list-group-item"><i class="@classIcon"></i>  @find.Col1</li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can somebody explain why the function is not running when I click on the list box?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: How you know you're clicking on `ul` and not `li`?

Comment: Explain it to vlaz, he thinks it's not a solution trying that

Comment: I tried setting it to li before ul, neither seemed to work. I am also using firefox inspect element to make sure I am clicking the correct thing

Comment: @LuisGar sure, explain it to me why click on the UL vs the LI is so important https://jsbin.com/fimamotafe/edit?console,output

Comment: Should see the user (not yours) css to answer that and other javascript. Is sure there are another events making the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Luis Gar suggests, you may be misunderstanding the structure / hierarchy of the elements and also how events 'bubble' up the structure. Event driven systems can be a minefield of unexpected sequence and unanticipated event triggering.

I have found it useful for my own understanding in a similar case to attach an onClick() function to all elements wherein the function would log to console 'clicked on ' + element.id. The benefit of this was to be able to understand which element was 'actually' being clicked and which elements received the bubbled event.

It's not a direct answer to your question but an approach that might help you in your journey up the learning curve.

I was using jquery and I think you are using some other library but it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not clicking the ul class='list-group'
Try to add a text and click it.

```
      <ul class="list-group"> CLICK ME
        @if (Model.fuzzyFind != null)
        {
            var classIcon = "";
            foreach (WebReg2.Models.FuzzyFind find in Model.fuzzyFind)
            {
                if (find.SmallIcon == "Elector") { classIcon = "fa fa-user fa-1x"; }
                if (find.SmallIcon == "ElectorPostal") { classIcon = "fa fa-user fa-1x"; }
                if (find.SmallIcon == "Deleted") { classIcon = "fa fa-trash fa-1x"; }
                if (find.SmallIcon == "Property Void") { classIcon = "fa fa-home fa-1x"; }

                <li class="list-group-item"><i class="@classIcon"></i>  @find.Col1</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
```

Comment: Clicking anything _inside_ the `<ul>` would emit a click event that should then bubble to the parent. What is the reason that wouldn't be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it worked.

have you try this one?

```
    $(function () {
      $('.list-group li').click(function (e) {
          $that = $(this);
          console.log($that);  
          $that.parent().children('li').removeClass('active-searchitem');
          $that.addClass('active-searchitem');
      })        
    })
```